# python jira return the content of a filter

Tags: python-jira

I'm new in jira python and I want to have a list with tickets obtained with an existing filter.

I tried `jira.filter(id)` but instead receiving the list with issue, I received only the name of the filter.
Using `jira.search_issue` is working, but because my filter can be change by other guys I need something that will take in account those changes of filter content.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use filter ID in `jira.search_issue`.

```
for i in jira.search_issues('filter=25471'):
    print i.key
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. I was sure that should be something easy :).

Comment: Note that this only returns the first 50 issues by default, you must use issues = jira.search_issues('filter=25471', maxResults=300) if you want more.

Comment: What to do if I want the filter ID to be a variable? I have multiple filters and I would like to search_issues multiple times.

Comment: @PranitiGupta you could do 'filter={}'.format(<YOUR VARIABLE>)